# Как распарсить xml строку с помощью java

Tags: java, dom, sax, парсер, jaxb

Подскажите каким образом в java (JAXB, SAX, DOM...) наиболее быстро и удобно можно распарсить xml вида:

```
<name="krt" null="false" value="S"/>
<name="trt" null="false" value="TW"/>
<name="gdf" null="false" value="SE"/>
<name="vcx" null="false" value="GGT"/>
<name="trg" null="false" value="NH"/>
```

В котором в java-переменные записывается значение `value` (к примеру, в `krt` запишется `S`, в `trt` запишется `TW` и т.д.)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите этот [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/index.htm), там описано как создавать `entity` и как из `xml` создать объект.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.